# Getting JPanels to overlap

Tags: java, swing

I am making Pong using Swing in Java. When adding JPanels to a JFrame they over lap and what ever one I put last is the one that shows. How do I get it so all of the objects (both paddles and the ball) show up?

```
public class Main {
    final static int WIDTH = 1000;
    final static int HEIGHT = 600;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //things for creating window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        //left paddle
        Paddle left = new Paddle(20,(HEIGHT/2)-100);
        frame.getContentPane().add(left);

        //right paddle
        Paddle right = new Paddle(WIDTH-60,(HEIGHT/2)-100);
        frame.getContentPane().add(right);

        //ball
        Ball ball = new Ball();
        frame.getContentPane().add(ball);
    }
}
```

Each object is its own JPanel object with the class extending JPanel and implementing paintComenent().

Comment: Why are you using components for this and not following a custom painted route?

Comment: Exactly as @MadProgrammer mentions above. Your Paddle and Ball classes shouldn't be component classes, classes that extend JComponent or JPanel but rather should be *logical* classes, classes that have state (location, for instance) and behavior (methods), and there should be one and only one component class that extends JPanel and that draws the state of the GUI.

Comment: I'm new to using Swing and quite honestly have no idea what I'm doing. I've just been Googling things until something somewhat works.

Comment: So what I need is to have my Main class extend JPanel and have that paint to the JFrame with the Ball and Paddle classes acting as logic for the objects?

Comment: @RyanLioy *"I've just been Googling things until something somewhat works."* - Ahhh, a true developer you will become 

Comment: *"So what I need is to have my Main class extend JPanel and have that paint to the JFrame with the Ball and Paddle classes acting as logic for the objects?"* Basically, yes - that would work. I'd rename the `Main` though, to something more descriptive like `PongTable`.